# Margin bottom as Keyboard height

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a function that gets the keyboard height

```
const useKeyboard = (): [number] => {
    const [keyboardHeight, setKeyboardHeight] = useState(0);

    function onKeyboardDidShow(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
        setKeyboardHeight(e.endCoordinates.height);
    }

    function onKeyboardDidHide(): void {
        setKeyboardHeight(0);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', onKeyboardDidShow);
        Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', onKeyboardDidHide);
        return (): void => {
            Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidShow', onKeyboardDidShow);
            Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidHide', onKeyboardDidHide);
        };
    }, []);

    return [keyboardHeight];
};
```

But this is not the full height

[image]

This gray bar is taller. Here it is cut off

How to do it to be correct?

I think this bar with GIF etc. above the keyboard is not included in height of keyboard

Answer (score 1):

You are almost well done. There is one problem with new phones

In Android (Java) it is called `navigation_bar_height`. (This is the bottom bar, which contains buttons formerly found on the bottom buttons of the phone)

We're talking about the bottom black bar

[image]

It must be added to the amount obtained by the previous method

```
const useKeyboard = (): [number] => {
    const [keyboardHeight, setKeyboardHeight] = useState(0);

    function onKeyboardDidShow(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
        let deviceH = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
        let windowH = Dimensions.get('window').height;
        let bottomNavBarH = deviceH - windowH;

        setKeyboardHeight(e.endCoordinates.height + bottomNavBarH);
    }

    function onKeyboardDidHide(): void {
        setKeyboardHeight(0);
    }

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', onKeyboardDidShow);
        Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', onKeyboardDidHide);
        return (): void => {
            Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidShow', onKeyboardDidShow);
            Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidHide', onKeyboardDidHide);
        };
    }, []);

    return [keyboardHeight];
};
```